# How can i modify the order of Micronaut Http Filter so it get executed after Micronaut Security

Tags: java, spring, filter, micronaut, micronaut-security

I have a checkForBankId annotation

```
@Target(value = { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(value=RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface checkForBankId {
    boolean ignore() default false;
}
```

And i have a BankIdSecurityService

```
public class BankIdSecurityService {

  /*
  * This is declarative client to call the
  * InternalAPIs to get all details about the user;
  */
  @Inject
  UserRepositoryClient client; 

  static final boolean AUTHORIZED = true;
  static final boolean UnAUTHENTICATED = false;

  Flowable<Boolean> checkAuthentication(HttpRequest<?> request) {
         
    if (routeMatch instanceof MethodBasedRouteMatch) {
         MethodBasedRouteMatch<?, ?> methodBasedRouteMatch = 
         (MethodBasedRouteMatch<?, ?>) routeMatch;

      if (methodBasedRouteMatch.hasAnnotation(checkForBankId.class)) {
             
           String userName = getUserName(request).get();
            
           if(!request.getParameter().contains("bankId")) {
                 return Flowable.just(UNAUTHORIZED);
             } 
            
           return this.client.getUser(userName).map(userDetails -> {

             String bankId = request.getParameter().get("bankId");
             BankAccount[] bankAccounts = userDetails.getPayload().getBankAccounts();
             boolean bankIdFound = false;
      
             for(BankAcconut bankAccout: bankAccounts) {
                  if(bankAccount.getId().equals(bankId)) {
                      bankIdFound = true;
                      break;
                    }      
                }

             return bankIdFound ? AUTHENTICATED : UNAUTHORIZED;
          });

        }
     }
     
     return Flowable.just(AUTHENTICATED);
  }

  Optional<String> getUserName(HttpRequest<?> request) {
    // get jwt from request header
       then parse the jwt and extract 
       the username from it and return;     
  }
}
```

then i have Filter which executes once per request

```
@Filter(Filter.MATCH_ALL_PATTERN)
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class BankIdSecurityFilter extends OncePerRequestHttpServerFilter {

    private final BankIdSecurityService bankIdSecurityService;

    @Override
    protected Publisher<MutableHttpResponse<?>> doFilterOnce(
     HttpRequest<?> request, ServerFilterChain chain
    ) {
        log.info("request route: {}", request);

        return this.bankIdSecurityService
            .checkAuthentication(request).switchMap(authResult -> {
                log.info("authentication result: {}", authResult);

                return authResult ? // if authResult is true then proceed as usual
                    chain.proceed(request) :
                    Publishers.just(HttpResponse.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                        .body("This bankId doesn't belond to this user.")
                    ); // return bad request
            });
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return ServerFilterPhase.SECURITY.after();
    }
}
```

Inside controller we apply the @CheckForBankId where we want to filter the request

```
   @CheckForBankId
   @GET("get-bank-account?{bankId}")
   Single<BankAccount> getBankAccount(String bankId) {
     return someService.getBankAccount(bankId);     
   }
```

The filter is working fine. The thing which is missing is that it gets executed before microanut
security so, the token which is coming in header is unauthenticated and from some cases it can
lead to some problems like what if an expired token passed to an header and my parser will parse
the token and will return the user from it but it makes no sense as the token is already invalid. It should have already been reject before coming to the filter..so, like this filter to
get executed after micronaut security. I tried overridding the getOrder method but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify which Micronaut version you're working with, but the answer is that the behavior is a bug. It should work as expected in Micronaut 2.5.4